# Number of operations needed to solve tridiagonal linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination, tridiagonal-matrices

> [image]

I was doing this question. I just checked some posts related to it, but didn't find anything suitable.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo you have original question in the image.. can you solve that ??? just that simpple

Comment: Removing your work makes your question worse, not better.